# JavaFX - SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> cannot be converted to SpinnerValueFactory<CAP#1> error

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Why am I getting this error

```
incompatible types: SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> cannot be converted to SpinnerValueFactory<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

I don't understand why, I have watched tutorials on how to set the value of a spinner, they all use something a long these lines

```
fx_amNpm.setEditable(true);
    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> test = new <Integer>SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, 100, 75);
    this.fx_amNpm.setValueFactory(test);
```

But for some reason my code won't compile.

Comment: Which line is giving the error? How is `fx_amNpm` declared (BTW please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java)).

Comment: My bad I just fixed the error, I thought scene builder made what type of object my spinner was accepting. I will mark this question as answered. Also my naming convention is fine, it suits what am using the variable for.

Comment: Your naming convention isn't the standard, accepted naming convention. It makes it very difficult for others to read your code - if you are sharing code in the hope of getting help with it, it's to your benefit to make it as readable for other people as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scene builder made my variable be

```
private Spinner<?> fx_amNpm;
```

But I had to make it

```
private Spinner<Integer> fx_amNpm = new Spinner<Integer>();
```

because it needed to know what type of object it was accepting.

Working code is

```
SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 5, 3);

    fx_amNpm.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
```

Comment: If scene builder is generating this code, it's presumably in a controller. If that's the case, you should not initialize it with `new Spinner<Integer>()` (because it will be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`). (Also, this answer is not really helpful to other users unless the cause of the problem is included in the question.)